# Making connection between sf::sound and qslidebar

Tags: c++, qt, audio, fft, sfml

I try to make a connection between `sf::sound` of `sfml` library and `QSlidebar` to have the timeline.

Does someone can give me some ideas to make FFT and display spiral circle by using this library.

Thanks for your attention.

This is my function : [image]

Comment: Not really an answer but an alternative solution: There's this great [template 'DSP' project](http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=05Misc:A_Template_for_Audio_DSP_Applications) that is available for download that uses [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/), [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) & [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/) setup all within QT. Maybe worth checking out for your task.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, i check this.